# A Google search of this BigQuery error doesn't return any exact matches. Do you know what it means?

Tags: google-bigquery

Error: 2.1 - 0.0: JOIN cannot be applied directly to a table union or to a table wildcard function. Consider wrapping the table union or table wildcard function in a subquery (e.g., SELECT *).

Job ID: [redacted]:job_pL4_bJxV7X02bltG3KrpxwqYkrQ

Comment: Could you post the query itself, and the explanation is quite straigtforward, did it work?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The error message tells you *exactly* what's wrong, and *exactly* how to fix it. What is your question? And if it's *How do I fix my SQL statement?*, how do you expect us to answer that without your including your SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will reproduce that error:

```
SELECT a.x, b.x
FROM (SELECT 1 x), (SELECT 1 x) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 x) b
```

To fix it, surround the union with a SELECT:

```
SELECT a.x, b.x
FROM (SELECT x FROM (SELECT 1 x), (SELECT 2 x)) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 x) b
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe, this makes sense.